# Skyline in haskell, probably cause ´function´is applied to too few arguments

Tags: haskell

i'm learning haskell for the university, i´m trying to do a Skyline problem -> https://briangordon.github.io/2014/08/the-skyline-problem.html

I have serious problems with haskell syntax because i come from OO languages, FP is weird for me, so, this is my current code:

```
    type Edificio = (Int,Int,Int)
type Coordenada = (Int,Int)
type Skyline = [Coordenada]

resuelveSkyline :: [Edificio] -> Skyline
resuelveSkyline [] = []
resuelveSkyline [x] = edificioAskyline(x)
resuelveSkyline xs = combina (resuelveSkyline(fst(divide(xs))),resuelveSkyline(snd(divide(xs))))

edificioAskyline :: Edificio -> Skyline
edificioAskyline (x1,x2,h) = [(x1,h),(x2,0)]

divide :: [Edificio] -> ([Edificio], [Edificio])
divide edificios = splitAt (((length edificios) + 1) `div` 2) edificios

combina :: Skyline -> Skyline -> Skyline
combina (_,_) = []
```

I have two questions, first one is:

I have a type Coordenada for example, what should i do if i want to pass a Coordenada as argument for other function and inside it get his first tuple value inside it?

The second one is, i´m having this error while compiles:

```
 Main.hs:8:22:
    Couldn't match type ‘Skyline -> Skyline’ with ‘[Coordenada]’
    Expected type: Skyline
      Actual type: Skyline -> Skyline
    Probable cause: ‘combina’ is applied to too few arguments
    In the expression:
      combina
        (resuelveSkyline (fst (divide (xs))), 
         resuelveSkyline (snd (divide (xs))))
    In an equation for ‘resuelveSkyline’:
        resuelveSkyline xs
          = combina
              (resuelveSkyline (fst (divide (xs))), 
               resuelveSkyline (snd (divide (xs))))
```

I known that merge isn´t still finished but i want to try do it little by little.

I have it in Spanish because i must use these function names mandatory (Professor obligates us).
I will explain each method.

resuelveSkyline has as a input a list of Edificio and return a Skyline, its the main function.
edificioASkyline has as a input a building and convert it a skyline
divide takes a list and return a 2 lists with same size.
combina takes 2 skylines and return a new one merged with both.

Comment: the error is just that you have to provide two *arguments* to your `combina` but you only provided one - sadly I have a hard time to translate this both to the problem-set and to some language I understand (I guess it's spanish?) so can you try tear the problem down and explain what your functions are supposed to be doing?

Comment: Yes, i will, just a moment :)

Comment: Im using combina(firstMiddleOfList,secondMiddleOfList) that is not right?

Comment: @colymore: no. That would be `(Skyline, Skyline) -> Skyline`.

Comment: Can you explain me why?Im beginner :D. Works, thanks

Comment: @Carsten: `Edificio = Building`, `Coordenada = Coordinates`, `resuelveSkyline = toSkyline`, `edificioAskyline = buildingToSkyline`. A `Skyline` the projection of a row of buildings, the skyline problem tries to yield a representation of that projection with a bunch of rectangles.

Comment: @Zeta thanks but I have trouble seeing how I can contribute anything meaningful aside from solving the problem and explaining every step - I think that there are so much fundamental misconceptions left that this problem is way to hard to start with

Comment: @colymore if you have a function `f :: (a,b) -> c` then you can think of it having one argument which is a tuple of an `a` and a `b` - so you have to invoke `f` like this: `f (a,b)` - if you have `f :: a -> b -> c` than you can think of it as having two arguments (there is a deeper meaning which you will learn about later but stick with this idea for now) and you should invoke it like `f a b` instead

Comment: @Carsten im just looking for get anwsers for my questions, not a resolution for the problem :).

Comment: And about use fields of a type synonyms?

Comment: @colymore I think you have enough problems with understanding the language and you should start there - if I remember correctly this was one of the non-trivial facebook(?) problems that started appearing a few years back - so now you have 2 problems: rewire your brain to FP and solve a harder problem

Comment: This problem is my homework for career..I should do it, but thank for the recomendation :).

Comment: @Carsten: Nah. Don't rewire your brain. Just open up a new, unused section. Imperative and OO thinking is still handy in the economy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to define `func :: A -> B -> C`. The syntax to define func would be:

```
func :: A -> B -> C
func a b = ...
  -- ^^^
```

However, if you use `(a,b)`, you're not using two separate arguments, but a single pair:

```
--      vvvvv
func :: (A,B) -> C
func (a,b) = ...
--   ^^^^^
```

However, GHC only looks `combina`'s type signature in this line:

```
resuelveSkyline xs = combina (resuelveSkyline(fst(divide(xs))),resuelveSkyline(snd(divide(xs))))
```

So although you've defined `combina` to work on tuples, it does not type check. Note that `combina's` definition would also not unify with its stated type.

That being said, if you change the type of `combina` and introduce a helper, you can make your code a lot easier:

```
combina :: (Skyline, Skyline) -> Skyline
combina  (a,b) = ...

both :: (a -> b) -> (a,a) -> (b,b)
both f (x,y) = (f x, f y)

resuelveSkyline xs = combina (both resuelveSkyline (divide xs))
```

### Exercises

1. You can change any function from `(a, b) -> c` to `a -> b -> c`. Write a function that does exactly that:

   ```
   fromPairFunc :: ((a,b) -> c) -> (a -> b -> c)
   fromPairFunc f = ...
   ```
2. You can also do the opposite. Write the according function:

   ```
   toPairFunc :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((a,b) -> c)
   toPairFunc f = ...
   ```
3. In your original code, don't change the type of `combina`, but correct its definition and use `toPairFunc` at the correct place.
4. In your original code, change the type of `combina`, but not the defintion. Instead of `(resuelveSkyline(fst(divide(xs))),resuelveSkyline(snd(divide(xs))))`, call it with two arguments `(resuelveSkyline(fst(divide(xs))))` and `(resuelveSkyline(snd(divide(xs))))`. You have to use `toPairFunc` at the correct place.

Comment: Thanks, i will do it :)